# Fix Avro filename with spring data hadoop

Tags: java, spring, avro, spring-data-hadoop

My goal is to write a directory on HDFS. For that I use:

- spring-data-hadoop:2.4.0.RELEASE
- spring-data-hadoop-store:2.4.0.RELEASE

In my config class I define a bean

```
@Bean
public DataStoreWriter<File> dataStoreWriter() {
        return new AvroPojoDatasetStoreWriter<File>(File.class, datasetRepositoryFactory(), fileInfoDatasetDefinition());
}
```

In my service I can use this bean to write what I want :

```
File myDirectory = new File(myDirectoryPath);
dataStoreWriter.write(myDirectory);
```

It works fine, on HDFS I have an avro file.
The name is generated and I can't find a solution to apply a file name strategy on it.

How could I fix the name or get the bean?

Comment: for information, http://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/2.4.0.RELEASE/reference/html/springandhadoop-store.html
says : "Currently, you can’t provide your own schema. This is something that we are considering changing in upcomming releases."